# reading characters from a file

Tags: java, filestream

i want to read a file one character at a time and write the contents of first file to another file one character at a time.

i have asked this question earlier also but didnt get a satisfactory answer.....
i am able to read the file and print it out to std o/p.but cant write the same read character to a file.

Answer (score 2):

It may have been useful to link to your previous question to see what was unsatisfactory. Here's a basic example:

```
public static void copy( File src, File dest ) throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new FileReader(src);
    Writer writer = new FileWriter(dest);

    int oneChar = 0;
    while( (oneChar = reader.read()) != -1 ) {
        writer.write(oneChar);
    }

    writer.close();
    reader.close();     
}
```

Additional things to consider:

- wrap reader/writer with BufferedReader/Writer for better performance
- the close calls should be in a finally block to prevent resource leaks

Answer (score 0):

You can read characters from a file by using a [`FileReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) (there's a [`read`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read()) method that lets you do it one character at a time if you like), and you can write characters to a file using a [`FileWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) (there's a one-character-at-a-time [`write`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write(int)) method). There are also methods to do blocks of characters rather than one character at a time, but you seemed to want those, so...

That's great if you're not worried about setting the character encoding. If you are, look at using [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and [`FileOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) with [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) wrappers (respectively). The `FileInputStream` and `FileoutputStream` classes work with bytes, and then the stream reader/writers work with converting bytes to characters according to the encoding you choose.

Comment: I wouldn't advise FileReader and FileWriter personally - they don't let you specify the encoding to use.

Comment: @Jon: Good point, though in this case I think encodings are probably going to get a bit beyond where the OP is right now.